# How to keep track of duplicated rows in a data frame when do a reduction by unique(df)?

Tags: r

This is a followup question of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/removing-duplicated-rows-data-frame-in-r).

Imagine the following data frame:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("A",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

which gives

```
  a b
1 A 1
2 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 1
6 B 1
7 A 2
8 A 2
```

I reduce it to it's unique rows by:

```
df_unique <- unique(df)
```

Now, I am wondering how can I keep track of the merged rows. I would like to create a new column in which each component has a list of row names that have been merged. Something like the following:

```
df_unique_informative =   
  a b track
1 A 1 [1,2]
3 A 2 [3,7,8]
4 B 4 [4]
5 B 1 [5,6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = aggregate(x = list(track = 1:NROW(df)), by = list(a = df$a, b = df$b), function(x) x)
# OR perhaps you want
#res = aggregate(x = list(track = 1:NROW(df)), by = list(a = df$a, b = df$b), function(x)
#                                                                paste(x, collapse = ", "))
res
#  a b   track
#1 A 1    1, 2
#2 B 1    5, 6
#3 A 2 3, 7, 8
#4 B 4       4

#Shorter code
res = aggregate(list(track = 1:NROW(df)), df[,1:2], '[')
```

**Update**

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("A",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
c = letters[1:8]
df <-data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
res = aggregate(x = list(track = 1:NROW(df)), by = list(a = df$a, b = df$b), function(x) df$c[x])
res
#  a b   track
#1 A 1    a, b
#2 B 1    e, f
#3 A 2 c, g, h
#4 B 4       d
```

Comment: The only is that when I recall `res$track` it is not a list of list. Do you have any suggestion to fix that? I would like to have [[1]] as 1, 2, [[2]] as 5, 6, [[3]] as 3, 7, 8, and so on.

Comment: no worries. I guess my new problem is that I don't know how to make sure I keep track of a non aggregated column. For example imagine the row.name column as a column 'c'. How can I aggregate on columns `a` and `b` but not `c`, however I want to save the track of `c` as a list of lists. Just like what previously was addressed in row.names, but for a column.

Comment: res = aggregate(list(track = c), df[,1:2], '['), I believe. Can you plz confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% 
         group_by(a, b) %>% 
         summarise(track = list(rn))
```